# Is is possible to create a wating queue infant of a load point, which stores Agent until the load point is free?

Tags: anylogic

I want to create a an AGV Storage. I want to create a queue in front of the Workingstation so the AGVs are waiting in front of them until they are free. At the moment the AGVs are waiting under the storage.

I tried to enter restricted areas in front of the working station. But the agvs are assigned to a random waiting area instead of the Workingstation they are headed to. Additionally they aren't path guided in front of the Working station. It would also be satisfying if it would work only for one working station.

[image: Property of Load Area]
[image: Function for acces denied]
[image: Function for access denied]
[image: My Process Flow looks like this]